# Header not sent though previously it was working

Tags: php, html, header

Using PHP Header method to redirect to another page after sending submit button had a problem though previously it was working fine. The problem started after putting additional form field.

Tried looking for any whitespaces, remove the code to the previous working state proved futile.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $hostname_mysql = "localhost";
    $database_mysql = "smartsaf_angkasa";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $mysql = mysql_connect($hostname_mysql, $username, $password);

    $errors = array();
    //mysql_select_db( $database_mysql, $mysql);

    if(!$mysql)
        echo "".mysql_error();
    else{
        //echo "<h2>Connected to database successfully ".mysql_error()."</h2>";
        mysql_select_db($database_mysql);
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {
?>  

<div>

  <form class="main-container" action="admin-pakej.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="input-form"><label for="desc" name="lbldesc">Description</label></div><div class="input-form-right"><input type="text" name="description" size="60" required ></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form"><label for="Market Price" name="lblmarketprice">Market Price</label></div><div class="input-form-right"><input type="text" name="marketprice" id="marketprice" size="20" required ></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form"><label for="Membership No" name="lblmemberno">Membership Number</label></div><div class="input-form-right"><input type="text" name="membershipno" id="membershipno" size="20" onblur="change()" ><div id="disabled-text-box"><input type="text" name="membersname" size="35" disabled></div></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form"><label for="Member Price" name="lblmemberprice">Members Price</label></div><div class="input-form-right"><input type="text" name="membersprice" id="membersprice" size="20" required ></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form"><label for="Point PV" name="lblpointpv">PV Points</label></div><div class="input-form-right"><input type="text" name="pointpv" id="pointpv" size="20" required ></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form"><label for="Package Type" name="lblpackagetype">Package Type</label></div><div class="input-form-right"><select name="package" id="package"><option value="gold">Gold</option><option value="silver">Silver</option><option value="bronze">Bronze</option></select></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form"><label for="Product Page" name="lblproductpage">Product Page HTML File Name</label></div><div class="input-form-right"><input type="text" id="productpage" name="productpage" size="30"></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form"><label for="Product Pics" name="lblproductpics">Product Pics</label></div><div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form-right"></div><div class="input-form-right"><input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" onchange="readURL(this)"></input><img id="blah" class="container" src="#" alt="preview image" /></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="input-form"></div><div class="button"><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></div>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <div><p>
    <!--<ul>-->
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        $desc_product = $_POST['description'];
        $membershipno = $_POST['membershipno'];
        $product_pics = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
        $market_price = $_POST['marketprice'];
        $membersprice = $_POST['membersprice'];
        $package_type = $_POST['package'];
        $pv_points = $_POST['pointpv'];
        $productpage = $_POST['productpage'];


    if (empty($desc_product) || empty($product_pics) || empty($membershipno) || empty($membersprice) || empty($pv_points) || empty($productpage))
    {
        array_push($errors, "Fields are empty");
    }
    else
    {           
        $query = "INSERT INTO product_final (desc, ext_member_id, productpics, marketprice, memberprice, packagetype, pv_points, productpage, category) VALUES
                                ('$desc_product', '$membershipno', '$product_pics', '$market_price', '$membersprice', '$package_type', '$pv_points', '$productpage', '')'";

        $result = mysql_query($query, $mysql);

        if ($result)
        {
            if (!headers_sent())
            {
                header("location:record_page.php");
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Headers already sent";
                exit;
            }
        }
        //else
            //echo "".mysql_error($mysql);
    }

}
?>
    <!--</ul>--></p>
    </div>
 </body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input)
    {
        if (input.files && input.files[0])
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload  = function(e)
            {
                $("#blah")
                .attr("src", e.target.result)
                .width(300)
                .height(250);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    function getpicPath()
    {
        document.getElementById("imgs").innerHTML;

    }


</script>
</html>
```

Expect to get at least an error message to find out what is actually holding the process from sending committed form submission to another page as acknowledgement that the form has already been processed.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and removed library now. Please switch toward `PHP7` along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO` library. Also use **_prepared statements_** feature of theses libraries to prevent your code from **_SQL INJECTION_**

Comment: i need to use version 5 because it is currently applied at the server. current direction is we are not upgrading. but anyway i will look into prepared statement. Kinda new thing for me. just started back what i hv long missed out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
if(mysql_affeted_rows($result)==1)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
            {
                header("location:record_page.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Headers already sent";
                exit;
            }
}
```

instead of that condition and once you have redirected through header I don't think you need to use `exit()`.
thank you.

Comment: `exit` or `die` is must after `header()`  redirect. Because `header()` redirect doesn't stop program execution although it redirected you to  a new page. That's why it will create a big security loophole if you are not adding `exit` or `die` after it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this problem basically because some HTML code is included (which is sending the header before only) right before you are trying to send header.
Your form code is sending header initially only, thereby making it impossible to send a http header later.
Use output buffering, i.e. at the very start of your script, put ob_start(), and at the end, put ob_flush(). This enables PHP to first wait for all the output to be gathered, determine in what order to render it, and outputs it.

[guide for using output buffer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Comment: thank you rishabh. done several checks now I found out that what actually messed up was the content of the form I am sending. if i remove enctype="multipart/form-data" from the form header I am able to get all the data except for the upload file. If I put it back again none of the data are sent after clicking Submit button. why is this happening?

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" is to get the files uploaded, and when it's removed, the files won't upload. I suggest adding ob_start(); at very beginning of the PHP code.